# Users accept the challenge (wordpress data logic)

Tags: wordpress, relationship

I'm working on a project and do not understand how I can relate data between users and post in wordpress. It is about creating a custom post that challenges users to do "something" and users decide whether to accept the challenge pressing a button (for example). I would understand the logic of data to then create querys of relations between users and "challenges".

Could you guide me how to relate many users to a post? ¿Custom fields?

Thank you!

Comment: I can give you some hints where to look. Look for `update_post_meta()`, `update_user_meta`, `add_action()`, `init` action. etc. You can update the list of user who accepted the challenge using `update_post_meta()` and also save the challenge id with individual user using `update_user_meta`. You can process the request using the `add_action('init', 'your_custom_callback_function')` inside `your_custom_callback_function()`

Comment: Thanks, I begin to understand.

Comment: I got it! It is working perfectly , now I have a problem with the admin screen , I create another question to see if anyone can help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends on the senario, and you have not described exactly what you want. So here is a general example.

**Lets say you have a custom post type of 'Exam' and you want to challenge the user to answer a question.** The question can be a custom field named 'question1' within that 'Exam' post type. The answer of every question will be stored within the user's meta data. There is a table in wordpress called wp_user_meta which stores all the user related fields.

When someone answers this question you will have to add the answer to that logged in user's meta data. So you can do something like

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'question1', 'Answer1' );
```

Now every user will have its own answers stored in their meta. To fetch the answers you do

```
get_user_meta( $user_id, 'question1', TRUE );
```

**Note:** Its great for small applications but as you can see if you have 50 questions and 10 users and all users answer the questions there will be 500 rows in the user meta, which becomes pretty large quickly. So a better way for this kind of data rich application would be to use serialization where you can house all the 50 answers in a single row.

Comment: Thanks, I begin to understand. The esecenario would be:
- Admin publishes a custom post (Challenge sing a song)
- The registered user accepts the challenge pressing a button (custom field stored on your user_meta?)
- By query on the main page (for example) I show a list of challenges and users who have accepted, like this:

Challenge "Sing a song" Users ACEPTED: User1, User2, User3 ...
Challenge "cooking a cake" Users ACEPTED: User5, user9 ...

So I relate the custom field with id post?

Comment: Yes, that right. You can also use "advanced custom fields" plugin to make it easier to add custom fields to a post type. with acf you can use get_field function to fetch the custom field.

Comment: I made it !! Thank you very much !